# Can't install mysql in raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi

I am trouble installing mysql, I have this broken package return on installing mysql error.

This is what tutorial I followed below:

[image]

and this is the result
[image]

**EDIT1:**
I followed Sebastian Dixon's answer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before you install, it is important to run update and upgrade;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server nginx
```

Hope this helps.